# Identifying Some Kind Of Fossil

Tags: species-identification, palaeontology

This was found off the coast of Ireland by a friend of mine. The running gag is it's some kind of fetish or totem and should be immediately discarded, but we're interested in whether it's perhaps a coronal section of a fish skull, a bivalve or something else entirely. Many thanks to anyone participating!

Attachments :

Image-1
[image: first image]
[(higher resolution)](https://s9.postimg.org/soz9v48gf/20170225_212722.jpg)

Image-2
[image: second image]
[(higher resolution)](https://s14.postimg.org/pydq0yl0h/20170225_212727.jpg)

Image-3
[image: (Third image)]
[higher resolution](https://s21.postimg.org/dvg76a147/20170225_212731.jpg)

Comment: Mostly speculation on my part but the patterns and configuration look like a sand dollar to me. Likely a species in the order Clypeasteroida.

Comment: I've shared a link of this to the [EarthScience.SE chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/37847985#37847985) to see if we can get some geologist eyes on this as well.

Comment: looks like the fossil Brachiopod

Comment: The best page on the web to find fossil ID experts is: Fossil ID - The Fossil Forum ... There was a molar ID on this forum some time ago, and the fossil forum guys knew what it was the same day.

Comment: Coronal cross section of a fish skull to me!

Comment: I know this is quite old - but those two oval marks could be [limpet home scars](https://marinebiology.org/tag/home-scar/)

Comment: I don't know what kind of fossil is this. But, I can help you with link to website called FossilID, here you just have to fill a submission form and Expert paleontologists will answer you and help you identify this one. **Here's the link:** https://form.jotform.com/221665322452047 Also, you can try downloading an app called Digital Atlas of Ancient Life. Available both on Apple App Store and Play Store. If you want you can use other online services.

Comment: looks like part of an echinoid aka sea urchin skeleton. there is a huge variety of shapes and patterns, especially when you start looking at fossil ones.